# What's wrong with this behaviour of "stdin"?

Tags: c, unix, io

I was testing how system call 'poll' works. But while I was doing that, I faced with an unclear behaviour.
Consider the following easy example:

```
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    pollfd p[2];
    p[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    p[0].events = POLLIN;

    p[1].fd = STDOUT_FILENO;
    p[1].events = POLLOUT;

    char *str_to_write = "Hello world!";

    write(STDIN_FILENO,
          str_to_write,
          strlen(str_to_write));

    const int NUMBER_OF_DESCRIPTORS = 2;
    const int DELAY = 5;

    int rt = poll(p,
                  NUMBER_OF_DESCRIPTORS,
                  DELAY * 1000);

    if (rt == -1)
    {
        printf("Some error was occurred! %d", errno);

        return errno;
    }

    if (rt == 0)
    {
        printf("Timeout was occurred! None of the events are ready =( ");

        return 0;
    }

    if (p[0].revents & POLLIN)
    {
        printf("stdin was ready =)");
    }

    if (p[1].revents & POLLOUT)
    {
        printf("stdout was ready =)");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

As we can see, I'm going to wait for a standard input stream until it's ready to be read:

```
 p[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
 p[0].events = POLLIN;
```

That's why I decided to write something there by the method 'write':

```
write(STDIN_FILENO,
str_to_write,
strlen(str_to_write));
```

Could you please clarify the following questions:
1) Why my idea of writing something to 'STDIN' and then get an event that would tell us that 'STDIN' is ready to be read doesn't work?
2) When I start the program not in the debug mode, there is always the message "hello world" on the screen (As an output of my program. Except the message that stdout was ready), but when I start it in the debug mode there is no this message. What could it be? How come that that information which was written to 'STDIN' then would be appeared in 'STDOUT' directly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Standard input could be an input-only stream. Never write to it. If you want to test events, just start your program (without the `write` call) and enter something in the terminal.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude interesting but 'write' was finished successfully (a concrete number of bytes were written). How would you explain it? I mean why I shouldn't write anything to it?

Comment: @Greezlock  If stdin is associated with a terminal, the write may succeed and produce output on the terminal.  But that data went to the tty and is not available to be read by your program.

Comment: Is this C, or C++.  `#include <cstring>` does not look like C.

Comment: @Greezlock writing to stdin is not defined, that's all. The fact that it does something means nothing. You can't rely on any behavior. This is like screaming in front of a speaker...

Comment: Try piping output from another program to your program, and try to write to the input, and see what happens. As a general rule: Don't write to input. Especially since it will not do what you want it to do (add to the input buffer).